# How to take $\left(\sum_I a_{Ik}d_I\right)\wedge \left(\sum_J b_{Jk}d_J\right)$ (wedge product)

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, integration, exterior-algebra

I need to take the wedge product

$$w_{1k}\wedge w_{2k} = \left(\sum_I a_{Ik}d_I\right)\wedge \left(\sum_J b_{Jk}d_J\right)$$

indexed in $I$ and $J$ which are finite sets.

Can I express this as simply

$$\sum_{I,J} (a_{Ik}\wedge b_{Jk})d_I\wedge d_J$$

or something like that?

I need this because I want to prove that when there are $w_{1k}$ such that $w_{1k}\to w_1$ and $w_{2k}$ such that $w_{2k}\to w_2$, then the product $w_{1k}\wedge w_{2k}\to w_1\wedge w_2$
.

I'm considerng $w_1 = \sum_I a_I d_I$ and $w_2 = \sum_I b_I d_I$, therefore I need to know how $w_1\wedge w_2$ looks like so I can prove that $w_{1k}\wedge w_{2k}\to w_{1k}\wedge w_{2k}$

Comment: No wedge between coefficients. You'll only have wedge products between the basis vectors. Since wedge is bilinear, it's distributive. Since it anticommutes, we have $d_I\wedge d_J=-d_J\wedge d_I$.

Comment: You're right... The coeffcients are just going to multiply themselves, right? But I think I must keep the coefficient of the new form dependent on both $I$ and $J$, right?

Comment: Right. So the result is $\sum_{I<J}(a_{Ik}b_{Jk}-a_{Jk}b_{Ik})\,d_I\wedge d_J$.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe hmmm, I think I get it. You used the anticomutative property so the coefficients that multiply the 'swapped' version of $d_I\wedge d_J$ are just the negatives of the original coefficients, right? Does this converge to $w_1\wedge w_2$? How do I know exactly? The sum for $w_1\wedge w_2$ would be $\sum_{I<J}(a_Ib_J-a_Jb_I)$, right? Can I just say that the previous sum approaches this one? Is it true that $a_{Ik}b_{Jk}\to a_Ib_J$ when $a_{Ik}\to a_I$ and $b_{Jk}\to b_J$?